# optimize latest timestamp query mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, database-optimization

to get only data with latest timestamp i use the mysql query from this answer:

[fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-
for-a-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

my query is following:

```
SELECT stock_id,timestamp,price FROM market m1
                        WHERE timestamp = 
                            (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM market m2 WHERE m1.stock_id = m2.stock_id)
```

but it takes 10 minutes to execute.

what are the different options to optimize it? (mysql)

market has following schema: (sqlalchemy)

```
class Market(db.Model):
    stock_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('stock.id'),primary_key=True)
    timestamp=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    price=db.Column(db.Float)
```

Comment: More efficient ways to do groupwise-max:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a so-called *dependent subquery.* These can sometime be very inefficient.

You can use this subquery to retrieve the max timestamp for each stock_id value.

```
                   SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp, stock_id
                     FROM market
                    GROUP BY stock_id
```

Your compound primary key should make this quite fast because MySQL will do [a "loose index scan" to](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html#loose-index-scan) satisfy it.

Then you can use this as a subquery, as follows:

```
  SELECT m.stock_id, m.timestamp, m.price
    FROM market m
    JOIN (
                   SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp, stock_id
                     FROM market
                    GROUP BY stock_id
         ) maxt on m.stock_id = maxt.stock_id AND m.timestamp = maxt.timestamp
```

This, too, should exploit your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a so-called *dependent subquery.* These can sometimes be very inefficient, because the query planner repeats them for every value from the outer query (`m1.stock_id` in your case).

You can use this subquery to retrieve the max timestamp for each stock_id value.

```
                   SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp, stock_id
                     FROM market
                    GROUP BY stock_id
```

Your compound primary key should make this quite fast because MySQL will do [a "loose index scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-optimization.html#loose-index-scan)" to satisfy it.

Then you can use it as a subquery, as follows:

```
  SELECT m.stock_id, m.timestamp, m.price
    FROM market m
    JOIN (
                   SELECT MAX(timestamp) timestamp, stock_id
                     FROM market
                    GROUP BY stock_id
         ) maxt on m.stock_id = maxt.stock_id AND m.timestamp = maxt.timestamp
```

This, too, should exploit your primary key.   https://use-the-index-luke.com/